# Django [WinError 10053] on AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm making a website with Django which uses AJAX to post some information to the backend. The information in this case is the total time that a user has typed (from when he starts typing) to when he presses submit. However, for some reason I keep getting the error below in the command prompt. The browser console simply has `0:`, which represents an error in the POST. I have a bunch of print statements in the view that handles the post (`passage_result`) to help locate the error, and it seems that it has to do with the line `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="text/html")`, because every single print statement returns the expected answer.

Here is the error:

```
[04/Jan/2015 10:30:40] "POST /typer/passage_result/ HTTP/1.1" 200 140
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 391, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[04/Jan/2015 10:30:40] "POST /typer/passage_result/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 58785)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 391, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 613, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 129
, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 669, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 133, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Here is the `passage_result` view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def passage_result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get all of the information needed
        user_passage = request.POST.get('user_passage')
        total_time = request.POST.get('time_taken')
        current_passage = request.POST.get('original_passage')
        creation_date = request.POST.get('creation_time')
        user = request.user
        original_passage = Passage.objects.get(name=current_passage, user=user)

        print("THIS IS THE TOTAL TIME " + str(total_time))

        # Measure word length and character length so I can measure accuracy/wpm
        user_split = re.findall(r'((?:(?<=^\s)\s*)?\S+\s*(?=\s\S|$))', user_passage)
        user_wlength = len(user_split)
        user_clength = len(user_passage)

        # Compare both strings against one another
        errors, accuracy, error_indices = checkString.checkWord(original_passage.text_body, user_passage)

        print("Errors: "+ str(errors))
        print("Accuracy: " + str(accuracy))

        # Round up the numbers, calculate wpm and cpm
        accuracy = round(accuracy, 4)
        minutes = float(total_time) / float(60000)
        wpm = round(float(user_wlength/minutes), 2)
        cpm = round(float(user_clength/minutes), 2)

        overall = round((wpm + accuracy)/2, 2)

        # Create a passage result for this instance, and save it to the database

        passageResult = PassageResult(user=user, passage=original_passage, creation_date=creation_date, user_passage=user_passage, total_time=total_time,
                                  total_words=user_wlength, total_chars=user_clength, errors=errors, accuracy=accuracy,
                                  wpm=wpm, cpm=cpm, overall=overall)
        passageResult.save()

        # Get the ranking of each passage, and save it.
        sorted_results = PassageResult.objects.order_by('-overall')
        for i in range(0, len(sorted_results)-1):
            sorted_results[i].rank = i + 1
            sorted_results[i].save()
            print(sorted_results[i].rank)

        # Create the response data that will be dumped json style
        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'Passage submitted successfully!'
        response_data['user_text'] = passageResult.user_passage
        response_data['total_time'] = passageResult.total_time
        response_data['author'] = passageResult.user.username


        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="text/html"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="text/html"
        )
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
//Create a time so we can update it later
var time = (new Date()).getTime();

//function to update the time when the user starts typing
$('#id_user_passage').on('keyup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    time = (new Date()).getTime();
});

// function to get the total time the user typed from when he started to when
// he clicked the submit button, and POST the information to the backend,
// along with what he typed and when he submitted it.
 $('#passage_result_form').on('submit', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var total_time = (new Date()).getTime() - time;
     var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();
     console.log('Time passed : ' + total_time + ' milliseconds');
     console.log('form submitted!')
     $.ajax({
         url: "/typer/passage_result/",
         type: "POST",
         data: { 'user_passage': $('#id_user_passage').val(), 'original_passage': $("#name").text(), 'time_taken': total_time,
         'creation_time' : current_time},

         success: function (json) {
             total_time = 0;
             console.log(json);
             console.log("success");
         },

         error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
             $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: " + errmsg +
                 " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
             console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
         }
     });
     location.replace('/typer/result/');

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question and solved it by doing like this, just add "async: false" to the ajax